# media queries and styled components

Tags: media-queries, styled-components

I like to have all the media queries at one place, usually in the App.css file because when I want to change something  depending on the size I see all the components involved at once.

I am looking for a nice way to do so with styled components. There styles are usually attached to the file where the styled components are defined. I don't want to use wrappers to refer to them with className.

Does someone has a good way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

After a discussion following solution came up:

```
const reducer = (accumulated, [condition, css]) =>
accumulated +
`
@media(${condition}) {
    ${css[componentName]}
}
`
const addMedia = componentName => Object.entries(theme.media).reduce(reducer, "")
```

Now you have all the media queries at one place and you need just to add them within the styled component via:

```
${addMedia("componenName")}
```